# Mount persistent disks on instance restart

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a server that has a persistent disk that I mounted with safe_format_and_mount. When I restarted the instance that the disk did not get mounted automatically, which I now see is a feature from looking at the docs. It is suggested to put the safe mount command into the google startup script.

However I did not start this instance with a startup script. Is there any way I can do this now? I do not see that there is.

Alternatively I can try and use safe_format_and_mount in the upstart script for the service that needs the disk, in this case MongoDB. I have the feeling that unless I create a new instance with a startup script that this is my best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add meta data to you compute engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#updatinginstancemetadata) with key `startup-script` and value the bash script to mount the drive. That's it. The key is a reserved word and GCE will execute the value as a bash script.

You can add the meta data to an already existing instance.

Comment: Thanks - that will come in handy. After reading a few more threads on this kind of issue it seem that the disk may get mounter after the MongoDB service starts, so I would need to change that upstart and move that service start into the google start script. As I have little time I have put the mounting of the disk in the mongodb upstart script with a check for if the disk has not been mounted already as it only used by this service anyway.